# OKHTTP 3 request post params not transfer into Node server on Heroku

Tags: android, node.js, heroku, http-post, okhttp

I have troubles using OKHTTP 3 to transfer parameters into heroku node server.

> It works properly with Postman, but not working Android App.

- **Android codes** (parameters are undefined in Heroku logs at bottom)

  ```
  public void makePayment(String phone, String token, String type, double amount, final ResultListener listener){

      RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
              .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
              .addFormDataPart("phoneNumber", phone)
              .addFormDataPart("serviceType", type)
              .addFormDataPart("stripeToken", token)
              .addFormDataPart("serviceCost", String.valueOf(amount))
              .build();

      final Request request = new Request.Builder()
              .url(Const.URL_HEROKU_BASE+"payment/charge")
              .post(requestBody)
              .build();

      client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
              if (listener != null) {
                  listener.onResponse(false, e.getLocalizedMessage());
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
              if (listener != null) {
                  listener.onResponse(true, response.body().string());
              }
          }
      });
  }
  ```

  heroku logs
  [image]
- **Postman** (parameters are defined)
  [image]
- **Heroku Node Server** (Debugging)

  ```
  router.post('/charge', (req, res, next) => {

      const phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
      const serviceType = req.body.serviceType;
      const stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;
      const serviceCost = req.body.serviceCost;

      console.log('phoneNumber : ' + phoneNumber);
      console.log('serviceType : ' + serviceType);
      console.log('stripeToken : ' + stripeToken);
      console.log('serviceCost : ' + serviceCost);
           ... .... ....

    });
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem myself after researching a lot.

> Amazing [Volley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo)(Easy Fast Networking for Android) really help me out this issue properly from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html).

```
    String url = Const.URL_HEROKU_BASE + "payment/charge";

    final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
    params.put("phoneNumber", phone);
    params.put("stripeToken", token);
    params.put("serviceType", type);
    params.put("serviceCost", String.valueOf(amount));

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            return params;
        }
    };

    queue.add(strRequest);
```